# javascript minus sign in variable

Tags: javascript, variables

I've got an XML-file. After converting it to JSON I want to access some content within. This was possible. However, some variable within the JSON contain a `-` (minus sign). When I try to access it, Javascript interpret this as a calculation. Is the only way to workaround this to replace all the `-` signs?

Comment: Can you some code?

Comment: JSON **cannot** contain variables. Valid JSON is always single object or array

Comment: [Hyphen is not a minus sign](http://theweek.com/articles/460264/youre-using-that-dash-wrong).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `brackets` notation:

```
yourJson['ab-cd']; // access to 'ab-cd' property that contains '-' sign
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to define or access properties with special characters in them, you need to use string property names:

```
var obj = {
  'some-string-with-hyphens': true,
  'another-one': true
};

var another = obj['another-one'];
```